# How to use std::copy to copy all elements of a class instance's variable?

Tags: c++, c++98

I got a class called CANMessage and it takes in `unsigned _id`, `const char *_data` and `char _len` and some other stuff but I'll skip that:

```
CANMessage::CANMessage(unsigned _id, const char *_data, char _len...)
```

It is part of an mbed API CAN, but I hope to include only useful information. If needed, it is here: https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/mbed-os-api-doxy/_c_a_n_8h_source.html

So, for example, if I created a CANMessage instance like so:

```
CANMessage message;
can.read(message);      //stores a CAN frame in CANMessage
```

I can access the data like so:

```
  for (int i=0;i<message.len;i++) {
       pc.printf(" %02X",*(message.data+i));    //prints out the data one by one
  }
```

I have a vector called sendToPc which sends this data in a specific format.

```
vector<uint8_t> sendToPc;
```

As such, the first 4 elements will store the length and the rest of the bits stores the data. But I can't quite get to how to copy the data into it because I fail to understand how std::copy works. I'm confused about what is considered an input iterator here.

```
std::copy(/*first input op, last input op, output operator/*)
```

Does it want pointers to that data? I feel like the first input would be message.data, but in a vector I could just do vect.end() to get the last element, but how to get the last element of data in this instance?

I believe the output iterator would be `sendToPc.begin() + 4`.

How can I copy all of the data of class instance message to my vector sendToPc starting the storage from sendToPc[4]?

Please note I am using C++98.

**Edit:** Would this work instead? As long as I store the length in there first...

```
for (int i=0;i<message.len;i++) {
    CANdata.push_back(*(message.data+i));
}
```

Comment: `*(message.data+i)` is more commonly written as `message.data[i]`.

Comment: You should show the definition of the thing you want to copy from and of the thing you want to copy the data to.

Comment: "I'm confused about what is considered an input operator here." ... I am confused where you got the information that `std::copy` would take an input operator as parameter... it takes iterators, see eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: are you confusing "iterator" with "operator" ?

Comment: If we speak about 4 bytes with distinct bit meanings, I have the feeling [bit manipulation operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) are the more promising tool than `std::copy()`.

Comment: i couldnt find `data` in the code you linked. THe question can be boiled down to "how to use `std::copy` to copy from (put here whatever type data is) to (put here whatever is the type of the container you want to copy to)?", though neither of the two types is clear from the question. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: _As such, the first 4 bits will store the length and the rest of the bits stores the data._ vs. _sendToPc[4]_ Bits or Bytes? 4 bits are the "half" of first byte (or `char`) but `sendToPc[4]` would address the 5th byte (or `char`). I suspect some confusion (on my or your side). ;-)

Comment: I wish I knew where I can find the data type of data.... I don't really have any clue whatsoever where to find it.

Comment: Normally you use an IDE and Ctrl+Click on the type you are curious about. That jumps to the definition of the type. Maybe your IDE uses F2 or rightclick->Go To Definition instead. If you are not using an IDE consider getting one. Otherwise do it the hard way and search the include files for the type's name, maybe with a `struct` or `class` in front of it. IDEs and operating system tools can usually search for files with given content.